# Can maximum log likelihood take a value of 0?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood

Can maximum log likelihood take a value of 0 ? I am using nlminb() in R to  minimize a function that returns -sum(log(x)), and I am getting the  $objective from nlminb()  of my full model as 0 and null model as 0.47.

Comment: Why shouldn't it take such value..?

Comment: @Tim Since a likelihood is often defined as a *probability* and all probabilities are $1$ or less, the logarithm must not be positive.  Thus, a positive "log likelihood" can only be reported when shortcuts are taken to avoid computing a normalizing constant for the probability distribution or else probability *densities* are involved.  Therefore it seems like there's good motivation for this question.

Comment: @whuber agree, I asked so that the question is stated directly.

Answer (score 1):

> Can maximum log likelihood take a value of 0 ?

This boils down to "can a log-likelihood take a value of 0?", to which the answer is "certainly, yes"; log-likelihoods may be positive, negative or zero. Consider, for example, that densities can be greater than 1 and a product of things above and below 1 could happen to come out to be essentially 1.

However - and I suspect this might be the case here - it's common to shift log-likelihoods by common but arbitrary constants* (as long as it's the same arbitrary constant each time if you're making comparisons). In this situation it's quite possible that they're making it such that the full model has likelihood 0 (besides simplifying things like subsequent likelihood ratio tests, it may well be useful for numerical reasons).

* indeed Fisher defined likelihood up to a multiplicative constant, so some authors at least would say that's not just a common thing to do but actually part of *how likelihoods work*.

Comment: you said that the log likelihood can be "positive, negative or zero". But it is only positive if you set an offset, right?

Comment: No. Even if you define log-likelihood as exactly the log of the joint density it can be positive, since (obviously) density can be greater than 1.